# Как разделить строку на цифры и знаки?

Tags: java

Дана строка , являющаяся уравнением (23+95*54, например). Необходимо разделить её на два массива, один из которых содержит числа, а второй знаки. Как это сделать?

Comment: Проходите посимвольно всю строку, если символ является цифрой его в один массив. В остальных случаях - в другой. В чем проблема?

Comment: Просто хочется узнать, как сделать это с минимальными затратами времени и памяти

Comment: Предложенный мной вариант будет достаточно быстр и не будет требовать лишней памяти. Если нужно быстрее - пишите на сях.

Comment: Регулярные выражения работают быстрее на длинных строках, чем посимвольный обход.

Answer (score 2):

Проходите посимвольно всю строку, если символ является цифрой его в один массив. В остальных случаях - в другой. Этот вариант будет достаточно быстр и не будет требовать лишней памяти. Если нужно быстрее - пишите на сях.

Comment: Спасибо. А как добавлять числа, которые содержат больше двух знаков? Я решил это так:
`for (char i : data) {
            if (i == '+' || i == '*' || i == '-') {

                symbols.add(i);
                numbers.add(oper);
                oper = 0;
            }
            else {
                oper=oper * 10 + Character.getNumericValue(i);
            }
        }`
То есть банальным умножением предыдущего числа на 10 и прибавления нового к нему. Думал еще над вариантов с substring. Что лучше?

Comment: @Hitrene никаких проблем нет, это вы не полностью сформулировали задачу.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Character> listName = new ArrayList<Character>();
List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer("+-/*");
StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer("0123456789");
while(st1.hasMoreTokens()){
    numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
}
while(st2.hasMoreTokens()){
    listName.add(st.nextToken()); //вот тут возможно проблема, можно пошаманить и привести к уму
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы крайне признателен за комментарии к решению.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, набросал решение на регулярных выражениях:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while(true) {
            String input = br.readLine();
            Pattern pNum = Pattern.compile("\\b[0-9]\\.+\\b");
            Pattern pAct = Pattern.compile("[+\\-*/]");

            List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> acts = new ArrayList<>();

            Matcher mNum = pNum.matcher(input);
            Matcher mAct = pAct.matcher(input);

            while (mNum.find())
                System.out.println(mNum.group()); //вместо вывода добавляйте в список nums для дальнейшей работы с ними

            while (mAct.find())
                System.out.println(mAct.group()); //вместо вывода добавляйте в список acts для дальнейшей работы
        }
    }
}
```

Пример ввода/вывода:

**23+95*54**

```
23
95
54
+
*
```

**23+95*54 - 10050.21**

```
23
95
54
10050.21
+
*
-
```

А чтобы потом посчитать значение выражения, берите поочередно из nums и acts и считайте.